# Azure DevOps REST API Error To Remove User From A Security Group / Team

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I am using PowerShell to remove a user from a Team in a project .Below is the code.

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$groupid = "vssgp.UyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUxMjkzxx"
$memberid = "tester.deer@dmain.com"
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)"))

$saasheaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$saasheaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader")
$saasheaders.Add("Accept", "*/*")
$saasheaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
$saasheaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
$saasheaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/mycollectionname/_apis/GroupEntitlements/$groupid/members/$memberid`?api-version=5.1-preview.1" -Method 'DELETE' -Headers $saasheaders 
Write-Host "value is $result"
```

Below is the error I get

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The request is invalid."}}
+ ... result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I am following the documentation from this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/remove-member-from-group?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you try to list the group entitlements once, before removing members by using this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) call?

Comment: @Sridevi - you are correct, I get no entitlements when using the above REST API link you referred. Wondering how I can remove the users from the Teams using REST API or Azure CLI. just an fyi - When I use the Azure Cli to remove a user , it hangs

Comment: Could you include CLI command you are running to remove user by editing your question?

Comment: @Sridevi - I have posted the Azure CLI command error in a different post, didnt want to derail this conversation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76820577/azure-cli-azure-devops-hangs-when-trying-to-remove-user-from-a-security-group