# Azure CLI - Azure DevOps Hangs When Trying To Remove User From A Security Group / Team

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

For the group descriptor, when using add command it works fine

```
$subject = "vssgp.Uy0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXMjkz"
$useremail = "testerasd.wilkomn@domain.com"
$orgname = "myorgname"

az devops security group membership add --org "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/" --group-id $subject `
--member-id $useremail --debug --verbose
```

but when doing a remove, using the below az cli command, it hangs indefinitely and does not responds.

```
az devops security group membership remove --org "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/" --group-id $subject `
--member-id $useremail --debug --verbose
```

Below is the information after which it hangs when trying to remove a user ( taken only last few lines of verbose data )

```
at 0x01FEZ9B20>, <function register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x03B734F0>, <function DevCommandsLoader.post_parse_args at 0x03BF4388>]
INFO: az_command_data_logger: extension name: azure-devops
INFO: az_command_data_logger: extension version: 0.26.0
```

Here is the versions of my az cli

```
c:\ az --version

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
azure-cli                         2.34.1 *

core                              2.34.1 *
telemetry                          1.0.6 *

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.26.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.16.0
azure-mgmt-resource               20.0.0

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\userid\.azure\cliextensions'
```

Python (Windows) 3.8.9 (tags/v3.8.9:a743f81, Apr  6 2021, 13:22:56) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal

**Anyone able to replicate  the same scenario or am I doing something wrong ?**